# api call not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to do a simple to do app that does a request to a pokemon api and send me the result.

like this:

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>{{pokemon.forms}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      pokemon: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    requestPokemon() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2").then(value => {
          resolve(value);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        })
      });
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.requestPokemon().then(value => {
      pokemon = value;
    }).error(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**the issue is that i get the following error:**

Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: this.requestPokemon(...).then(...).error is not a function"

any help with this??

thanks

Comment: `requestPokemon` returns a Promise. Did you mean to `catch`?

Comment: just like your error message says, "`.error` is not a function".  [`Promise` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise) only come with `.then` and `.catch` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Replace error with catch, as the others said:

```
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      pokemon: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    requestPokemon() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2").then(value => {
          resolve(value);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        })
      });
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.requestPokemon().then(value => {
      pokemon = value;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `beforeMount` is not correct.
As oMiKeY said in his answer, you need to change `.error` to `.catch`
You also need to bind the response to `this.pokemon` (and not just pokemon)
Then, as `requestPokemon` function returns a Promise, you need to find the data in it :

```
  beforeMount() {
    this.requestPokemon().then(value => {
      this.pokemon = value.data
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```